# How often is the number between two twin primes divided by 6 a prime?

Tags: twin-primes, distribution-of-primes

This question has been edited thanks to the feedback by one user:

12 is in between 11 and 13, and 12/6 = 2 which is prime.

So if we take 29 and 31, 30 is in between, and 30/6=5 which is prime

In general, how often is the number between two twin primes divided by 6 a prime? Are there a finite number or infinite number of them?

Comment: As a complete aside, your question could have been rephrased as asking if there are only finitely many triples $(p,2p-1,2p+1)$ where all three are prime.  You would have had $p$ must be a [sophie germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime), which is still not known whether or not there are finitely many of them.

Comment: Heuristics suggest that there are about $\frac{N}{(\log N)^3}$ primes $p\in[1,N]$ such that both $6p-1$ and $6p+1$ are also primes, and it is not difficult to prove through sieve arguments that they cannot be much more than $\frac{cN}{(\log N)^3}$.

Comment: To get non-trivial lower bounds for the cardinality of a sifted set through a small sieve is notoriously (very) difficult: such technical issue is shared by the twin primes conjecture, Goldbach's conjecture, Sophie Germain's conjecture etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your new edit, asking for prime triplets $(p,6p-1,6p+1)$, this appears in OEIS as [sequence A060212](http://oeis.org/A060212).

It is unknown yet whether there are finitely many or infinitely many twin primes.  If there were finitely many, then this would obviously imply that there are finitely many prime triplets of the form you are interested in.

It is also unknown whether or not this sequence is infinite.

---

A related [forum post](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=21171), giving a 5000+ digit prime in the sequence.

Comment: Thank you. If there are finitely many twin primes, then there would be finitely many such triplets. However, if there are infinite many twin primes does not mean that there would be infinitely many such triplets

Comment: It is likely, but nothing I have read suggests that that problem has been solved.

Comment: "It is unknown..."  I hate to opinionate, but perhaps it isn't a worthwhile problem.  Otherwise some such ideas would have been advanced in an academic venue and the problem of, at least the weak form of the twin prime problem, would have been accepted as settled.  Long ago.

Comment: @JMoravitz these should occur within the same density (they are just as common) as prime triplets (p, p+2, p+6), (p, p+4, p+6), no?

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ and $p+2$ are prime and $p>3$ then $p$, $p+1$ and $p+2
$ are consecutive numbers and $p$ and $p+2$ are not multiple of $3$, so $p+1$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question using your feedback